# Location of Java installer for Windows Perimeter Server

Tags: ibm-sterling

ps_6010001.jar-this file but for Windows

Where do I find the Windows installer for a Java install on a perimeter server for Sterling Integrator 6010?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this documentation link: [Installing a perimeter server in a less secure network](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/b2b-integrator/6.1.0?topic=servers-installing-perimeter-server-in-less-secure-network).

You should always collect the **Perimeter Server** installer from **installed IBM Sterling B2B Integrator's instance's** `<install_dir>\packages\<ps_filename>.jar`.

Use the java version as per the Operating System's vendor like AIX, RHEL, Solaris etc.

Then run the executable installer jar using `java -jar`

```
/<path_to_java>/java -jar /<install_dir>/packages/<ps_filename>.jar –interactive
```

Follow the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/b2b-integrator/6.1.0?topic=servers-installing-perimeter-server-in-less-secure-network) for more details.